# How to train multiple losses in one model with freezing some part of the network optionally in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch. 
I'm implementing a network that has two classifiers(yellow and purple) as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxyUY.png). 
The problem is that I want to freeze the red part when the network trains the yellow classifier and unfreeze the red part when the network trains the purple classifier.

A brief code that I imagine to implement is bellow

```
# x is input and y_yellow, y_purple are labels of yellow and purple classifiers respectively.
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss()
opt = SGD()
model = my_model()

opt.zero_grad()
yellow_out, purple_out = model(x)

# freeze red part requires_grad = False

yellow_loss = criterion(yellow_out, y_yellow)
yellow_loss.backward()
opt.step()

opt.zero_grad()
# unfreeze red part requires_grad = True

purple_loss = criterion(purple_out, y_purple)
purple_loss.backward()
opt.step
```

Please let me know the exact way to implement the idea.

- Is the sequence of the code right?
- Did I use correctly the zero_grad?
- Did I miss something?
- Is there any optional parameter that I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest strategy would be to not pass the parameters of the red module to the optimizer `opt`. Alternatively, you could set the `requires_grad` as `False` for the parameters of the red module.

It will look something like:

```
for param in red_module.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Let me know if this works for you.